# Remove ContentType from list Office 365

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, powershell-2.0, office365

I want to remove a Content-Type from a list in office 365 using powershell. I found this code but the $Doclibrary is always null.

```
$lookForList = "Document"
$stringCTRemove = "Your Content type"
        $docLibrary = $_.Lists[$lookForList]


    if($docLibrary -ne $null)
    {
        $ctToRemove = $docLibrary.ContentTypes[$stringCTRemove]
        write-host "Removing content type" $ctToRemove.Name "from list" $docLibrary.Title
        $docLibrary.ContentTypes.Delete($ctToRemove.Id)
        $docLibrary.Update()
    }
    else
    {
        write-host "The list" $lookForList "does not exist in site" $_.Title
    }
}
```

solution:

```
function removeBannersCT ($web)
{
    $listName = "Banners"
    $list = $context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($listName)
    $context.Load($list)
    $context.ExecuteQuery()
    $stringCTRemove = "Picture"

        if($list -ne $null)
        {
            $lcontentTypes = $list.ContentTypes
            $context.Load($lcontentTypes)
            $context.ExecuteQuery()
            foreach($cts in $lcontentTypes)
            {
                if($cts.Name -eq $stringCTRemove)
                {
                    $list.ContentTypes.GetById($cts.Id).DeleteObject()
                    $list.Update()
                    write-host "Content-Type removed"
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            write-host "The list" $listName "does not exist in site"
        }
}
```

Please, Can you help me? I'm crazy!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: solved, I have to add the load context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go the solution, 
There are two methods one to remove by content type ID and other by content type name.

```
function Set-SPORemoveContentTypeByName {
[cmdletbinding()]
    param (
        [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext]$ctx, 
        [string]$spList,
        [string]$ctName
    )

    $web = $ctx.Web
    $list = $ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($spList)
    $cntTypeColl =$list.ContentTypes
    $ctx.Load($web) 
    $ctx.Load($list)
    $ctx.Load($cntTypeColl)
    $ctx.ExecuteQuery()



    foreach($ct in $cntTypeColl)
    {

    if($ct.Name -eq $ctName)
        {
        $ct.DeleteObject()
        break;
        }
    }

    $ctx.ExecuteQuery()

} 

function Set-SPORemoveContentTypeById {
[cmdletbinding()]
    param (
        [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext]$ctx, 
        [string]$spList,
        [string]$ctId
    )

    $web = $ctx.Web
    $list = $ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($spList)
    $cntTypeColl =$list.ContentTypes
    $ctx.Load($web) 
    $ctx.Load($list)
    $ctx.Load($cntTypeColl)
    $ctx.ExecuteQuery()

  write-host "Required Content Type Id :" $ctId

    foreach($ct in $cntTypeColl)
    {
    write-host "Intertaed ID " $ct.Id


    if($ct.Id.ToString() -eq $ctId)
        {
        $ct.DeleteObject()
        break;
        }
    }

    $ctx.ExecuteQuery()

}
```

Cheers,
Kiran